# Encrypting a string with a stack

Tags: c++, encryption, stack

I received an assignment for my C++ class last week. I think some of you will find it interesting! I managed to get most of the code down but I'm stuck and cannot figure this out for the life of me... Below are the guidelines for the encrypting process I must put into code:

> The message sender inputs a four letter word, **CCCC**, and another four letter word,
>   **XXXX**.  
>   The message sender then inputs the message to be encrypted.
>   The program scans the message one char at a time and each char is pushed in a stack until 
>   either the scanned character is in the word **CCCC** or the end of the message is 
>   encountered. 
>   When the scanned character is one of the chars in **CCCC**, print that char and continue 
>   to print and pop the chars at the top of the stack until either the stack is empty or the 
>   char at the top of the stack is one of the chars in **XXXX**. When the end of the
>   message is encountered, print the character at the top of the stack and continue to pop 
>   and print from the top of the stack until the stack is empty.
>   
> *Here is a hint: "**GOOD**"  "**LUCK**", it "**SOUNDS SIMPLE TO ME**", or as
>   your program would say: "**OSDNOT EEM LPMIS SU**"*

So that is the actual assignment.

What I am having trouble with is the last bit:

> When the end of the
>   message is encountered, print the character at the top of the stack and continue to pop 
>   and print from the top of the stack until the stack is empty.

now here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Stack
{
   private:
   char Chars[50];
   int top;
   public:
   int push(char);
   char pop();
   bool isEmpty();
   bool isFull();
   Stack()
   {
      top = 0;
   }
};

int main()
{
Stack theStack;
   char word1[4];
   char word2[4];
   for(int i=0; i < 4; i++){
      word1[i] = ' ';
      word2[i] = ' ';
   }
   char message[500];   
   cout << "Please enter a 4 letter word: ";
   cin >> word1;
   while(word1[4] || !word1[3])
   {
      cout << "Word must be 4 chars long. Try again: ";
      cin >> word1;
   }
   cout << "Please enter another 4 letter word: ";
   cin >> word2;
   while(word2[4] || !word2[3])
   {
      cout << "Word must be 4 chars long. Try again: ";
      cin >> word2;
   }
   cout << "Please enter the phrase to be encrypted (50 chars max): ";
   cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
   cin.getline(message,500);
   int length = strlen(message);
   int count = 0;
   char finalMsg[length];
   //scanner
   for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
   {
      if(message[i] == word1[0] ||
         message[i] == word1[1] ||
         message[i] == word1[2] ||
         message[i] == word1[3])
      {
         finalMsg[count] = message[i];
         count++;
         if(message[i-1] != word2[0] ||
            message[i-1] != word2[1] ||
            message[i-1] != word2[2] ||
            message[i-1] != word2[3])
         {
            finalMsg[count] =  message[i-1];
            count++;
         }
      }
      else
      {
         theStack.push(message[i]);
      }
   }
   cout << finalMsg << endl;
return 0;
}

int Stack::push(char data)
{
   Chars[top] = data;
   top++;
return top;
}

char Stack::pop()
{
   char ret = Chars[top-1];
   top--;
return ret;
}

bool Stack::isEmpty()
{
   if(top <= 0)
      return true;
   else return false;
}

bool Stack::isFull()
{
   if(top >= 50)
      return true;
   else return false;
}
```

When compiled, the final output gives me "**OSDNOT**" which is in the example provided by my professor, so I know I'm  heading down the right track.. Any help would be great, I don't even know where to begin to examine the code.

Comment: Double-check your declarations for `word1` and `word2`.

Comment: I'm not going to read through all of this code because it's late and I'm tired, but what I would do for all of my complex Computer Science homeworks is: make sure that you are printing out all of your variable values that are changing at every step.  That way you can see where the problem lies.

Comment: @sblom hmm why do you say that? It looks fine to me

Comment: @AlexW You're right, I should have posted this early or waited until tomorrow morning. Thanks for the tip though I will try that!

Comment: Wow, that's more of an anagram than an encryption. Keep this for that anagram assignment you know is coming up.

Comment: @RCorrie, my compiler actually gives me a warning that might help: "encrypt.cpp:32:10: warning: array index of '4' indexes past the end of an array (that contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]"

Comment: One specific thing you should check: what are the contents of the stack after your program has finished printing everything that it's going to print?

Comment: @sblom What are you using to compile? 

And thanks for the idea, I'll write a short function and see what happens!

Comment: @RCorrie, I got that from the compiler called [`clang`](http://clang.llvm.org/).

Comment: Instead of using a loop to initialize `word1` and `word2`, why not use an initializer? I.e. `char word1[] = { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' };`. Also note that those two arrays can only hold _three_ characters if you use them as strings, as they need the terminating `'\0'`. Further note that you access e.g. `word1[4]` which is outside the array, as indexes goes from zero to size-1.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ha! That's true, forgot about that! That's right, I forgot cstrings need the `'\0'`! One more correction I need to make, thanks! I'm accessing `word1[4]` just to check if the user is inputing more than the required characters, is there a better way?

Comment: You could use a long array, or even better a `std::string` and check the length. Then if it's okay copy it to the actual array.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks, I would actually do that but on my last assignment I used `std::string` and the professor took off points for it. I guess it's like how they don't let you use calculators in math class for most of grade school

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the corrected code. You didn't code the algorithm right. I have commented the changes i have made in the code.
first of all, you didn't pop out the elements of the stack when you encountered a character present in CCCC while scanning. Also at the end of scanning, you didn't empty the stack. Include `cstring` instead of `string`. As pointed out in the comments, your declaration for word1 and word2 is incorrect.

```
   char finalMsg[200];
   //scanner
   for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
   {
      if(message[i] == word1[0] ||
         message[i] == word1[1] ||
         message[i] == word1[2] ||
         message[i] == word1[3])
      {
         finalMsg[count] = message[i];
         count++;

         //pop out elements from the stack till it is empty or an character of XXXX is encountered
         while(!theStack.isEmpty())     
         {
             char tmp=theStack.pop();
             if(tmp==word2[0] ||
                tmp==word2[1] ||
                tmp==word2[2] ||
                tmp==word2[3])
                {
                    theStack.push(tmp);
                    break;
                }
            finalMsg[count++]=tmp;
         }

      }
      else
      {
         theStack.push(message[i]);
      }
   }

  //empty the stack
   while(!theStack.isEmpty())
   {
       finalMsg[count++]=theStack.pop();
   }
   finalMsg[count++]=0;
   cout << finalMsg << endl;
```

PS: Better use std::stack and std::string.

Comment: Works perfectly! I figured that's what was happening, thanks a lot.

Yeah the professor is teaching us about classes and he's using this as a way to teach it. 

Thanks again